# Query params where one parameter should only be available if another is present

Tags: rest, api, get, endpoint, query-string

I want to create an api endpoint that has this functionality:

`/foo?color=blue&shape=square` => return all blue squared foos

However, shape should only be an option if color is present, meaning:

`/foo?shape=square` => should not be possible.

Should I just return bad request when a consumer tries `/foo?shape=square` or is there a best practice that I don't know of regarding this case ?

Comment: what would you return if the color is present but invalid? e.g. `/foo?color=magenta-with-blue-dots&shape=square`

Comment: resource not found